# Ansible: output to dict instead of list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary with containers specified as follows (simplified):

```
container:
  - name: test1
  ...
  
  - name: test2
  ...
```

To create the test1 container, I can run it as follows:

```
- docker_container: "{{ containers[lookup('index_of', containers, 'eq', 'test1', 'name')] }}"
```

I thought I could simplify this as follows:

```
- docker_container: "{{ containers | selectattr('name', 'eq', 'test1') }}"
```

But the output is generated as a list instead of a dictionary.

Using debug, the output of both commands is:

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "test1"
```

vs

```
    "msg": {
        "name": "test1"
```

I'm still learning about jinja and ansible. How can I make this work? I tried adding `| dict` and `| flatten` at the end, but this throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the plugin first:

```
- docker_container: "{{ containers | selectattr('name', 'eq', 'test1') |first}}"
```